# C# Predicate builder with multiple Tables

Tags: c#, predicatebuilder

I have 2 Tables, `Receipts` which contains columns like `Id`, `InvoiceId` etc and `Invoices`, which Contains `Id`, `InvoiceNo`, `RevisionNo`.  A Receipt can have multiple Invoices. So in my receipts listing page there is a column called `InvoiceSet` which will display a list of (`InvoiceNo + RevisionNo`) in a comma separated manner

Eg : `2000155 A, 200111 B`

in a single column. I have a search field on top of my list page where a User can search the entire list using key words. For that purpose i am using predicatebuilder.  So when a user searches **200111 B** the list should filter and show the row which has the given search key. Since the given search key is a combination of invoiceNo and RevisionNo (200111 = invoiceno, B = RevisionNo) from Invoice table i am not able to build a predicate that can combine the two columns using predicatebuilder.

I tried like this :

```
p.Receipts.Any(a =>  a.Invoice.InvoiceNo + " " + a.Invoice.RevisionNo).Contains(criteria.Search.Value)
```

but it's giving me error stating

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type

*Both the InvoiceNo and RevisinNo is of type string*

Is it possible with predicatebuilder to acheive what i am looking for ?

Comment: the lambda in an `Any` should return a boolean. `a.Invoice.InvoiceNo + " " + a.Invoice.RevisionNo` isn't a boolean it's a string, hence your error

Comment: I can't help but feel this question contains an awful lot of superfluous information. I had to read a lot of text to get to your actual error.

Comment: @Liam Sorry with that long info. was looking for proper communication. the answer is there, which i have tested and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be:

```
p.Receipts.Any(a => (a.Invoice.InvoiceNo + " " + a.Invoice.RevisionNo).Contains(criteria.Search.Value))
```

Comment: you are rockstar... will accept this as answer in another 5 minutes